# Web services(asmx)discovery is it possible c#

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

suppose I have a url like :http://localhost:32432/
When I go to this url I see many files including asmx ones.

Is it possible given the url to get a list of all the asmx files ?

I need to list all web services for a given url?

Comment: If the webservice discovery is allowed by URL then only you can discover allowed web services list.

Comment: how do you do it?How do you make webservice discovery by url?

Comment: Please follow through this article, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t5yf68(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't want to be using ASMX at all. It's a legacy technology kept around for backwards compatibility only.

Second, no you generally can't enumeratlee the files within a "folder" over the Internet.

Finally, the entire idea of discovery is questionable in my mind. Once a client discovers a service, how would it know what to *do* with the service?

Comment: .Unfortunately I dont have a choice of technology. I wish I could use wcf.I am stuck for now on webservices on this project. It's for an internal application and I need to list all the web services rather than hardcoding them.Wondering if was possible to dynamically find all the webservices for a given URL.Lets put aside whether is questionable or not.Can it be done and how?many thanks

Comment: @john, The Idea of web service discovery is not an idea any more its a reality and to know how to discover and use the operations of webservice is all defined through multiple web service specifications published already (e.g. Web service definition Language WSDL).Whole cloud environment resides on this dynamic discovery and usage of services.

Comment: @Furqan: "whole cloud environment"? I had no idea.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Not Categorically but to much extent it relies on dynamic discovery and usage of existing web services.